# Creating maps in R: Missing islands?

Tags: r, maps

I am trying to map a harbour (Conception Bay South) in Newfoundland, Canada but, the main island (Bell island) is missing. I've been trying for days to figure out how to fix it.

When I add world.cities the city that is on that island shows up, but the island itself is missing.

I know that maps has a river layer and a lake layer that can be added as needed, but is there an island layer I'm just not finding? Or do I have to get the data some other way? If so, how would I do that?

I would prefer to not have to plot this in ggplot or ggmap, because for everything except the missing islands 'maps' is working perfectly for me. But I'll obviously do that if there isn't another solution.

Here is my code:

```
require(maps)
require(mapdata)
map('worldHires','Canada',
           xlim=c(-53.5, -52.500), 
           ylim=c(47.2,48.25), 
           col="grey75", fill=TRUE)
map.axes(cex.axis=0.8)
map.scale(-53.41,47.29,
          ratio=FALSE,
          relwidth=0.1,
          cex=0.5)
```

Comment: I tried to grab updated information from http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm2.8/rds/CAN_adm3.rds , following http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/10/geographic-maps-in-r.html (and looking in http://gadm.org/country ) , but my spatial-data-fu is not up to the task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the raster package to get level 2 admin data for Canada:

```
require(raster)
cdn = getData("GADM",country="CAN",level=2)
plot(cdn, xlim=c(-53.5, -52.500), ylim=c(47.2,48.25))
```

shows a small island in the bay and some more on the end of the peninsula.

This is a base R graphics plot, so use base plotting functions to put things on top, change the colour, axes etc.

Comment: Perfect! I knew there was a way. It just wasn't intuitively obvious :)

Comment: In fact, you can also use the maps package with the GADM data: map(cdn, xlim=c(-53.5, -52.500), ylim=c(47.2,48.25), namefield="NAME_2") will also work (provided you maps version >= 3.1.0).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the islands appear to be missing. A solution would be to use `ggmap` with `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggmap)
get_googlemap(center = "Conception Bay South", zoom = 10) %>% ggmap()
```

I should also point out, that if you have a .shp file, you can use that instead of `ggmap`.

Comment: Do we really need to pull in all of `dplyr` for a single pipe operation ... ? `g <- get_googlemap(...); ggmap(g)` ?

Comment: The issue with using google maps based maps is that they aren't publication quality for scientific journals. I am plotting a study site on the map (I didn't include that code cause it's not important for the question) as part of the methods section of a paper we are working on.

I havent played a lot with ggmaps. I assume I can get rid of the satellite view type maps?

Comment: @hpenney112, I haven't done this in years, but R is able to read shape files. Have you explored that option?